# ubuntu 18.10: pdf thumbnails does'nt work

Tags: 18.10

Although evince-thumbnailer is already installed and everything seems to be fine, no pdf thumbnails have appeared in Nautilus.

I tried two fresh installs in two different machines and one more in a virtual box machine and the funny thing is that if you boot in a live cd mode then the thumbnailer seems to work fine.

Comment: Can confirm that too!

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to purge evince with

```
sudo apt purge evince
```

and reinstall it with snap

```
snap install evince
```

After deleting `.cache/thumbnails` and a reboot, .pdf thumbnails immediately work.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a workaround [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1798091).

In brief:

1. Edit the file `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.evince` (e.g., `sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.evince`)
2. Add the line `owner /tmp/{,.}gnome_desktop_thumbnail.* w,` at the end of `usr.bin.evince` (in my case it was empty), and save.
3. Run the command `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`.

That's it! It works immediately...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the issue,

Actually, for me it works with "`owner /tmp/{,.}gnome-desktop-thumbnailer.* w,`" According to the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1798091) you have shared.

You have writen "`owner /tmp/{,.}gnome_desktop_thumbnail.* w,`" but it didn't works with this code. The différencies are "_" replaced by "-" and "thumbnail" replaced by "thumbnailer"