# Xubuntu 18.04 Thunar shows video and image thumbnails, but it doesn't show PDF covers

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, pdf, thunar, thumbnails

Xubuntu 18.04 Thunar shows video and image thumbnails, but it doesn't show PDF covers.

It did show PDF covers in the past, but no longer does.

Comment: is `evince` installed?

Comment: Yes evince is installed.

Comment: have you tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086285/ubuntu-18-10-pdf-thumbnails-doesnt-work

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. I have not, but will and will report the result!

Comment: @ptetteh227 Thanks! I've been trying to solve that forever. The procedure of reinstalling with snap solved the issue! I didn't even need to reboot!